# C# code to pass a stream which is compatible with COM interop

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop, navision

I have a function that looks like something below

```
 public bool GetDocList(string Token, bool StatusActive, string StatusName, string HubId, out Stream DocList)
    {
        ....
                DocList = GetDocListFromXML(documents);
         ....

    }
```

when this function is exposed to COM with navision backend , it is not accepting the Stream datatype. What are the possible alternatives so that it is COM compatible?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: And what is Nav version

Comment: "Not accepting" is awfully vague.  No particular problem with Stream, it is [ComVisible(true)].  Do not expect auto-completion.  Lots of Automation clients require reference arguments to be passed [in,out].  So use `ref` instead of `out`.